# How to get value from toggle-button yes/No And show retrieve data in button active

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

Hiii Everyone,

Below is my code to display toggle button yes/no.What i want to do is based on user selection i want to retrieve data.If they choose Yes toggle button javascript variable should have yes string or else no string.

HTML Code

```
<label class="switch">
  <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
  <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span> 
  <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
 </label>
```

CSS

```
  .switch {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.switch-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #eceeef;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.switch-label:before, .switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  -o-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
}
.switch-label:before {
  content: attr(data-off);
  right: 11px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.switch-label:after {
  content: attr(data-on);
  left: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
  background: #0088cc;
  border-color: #0088cc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-handle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-handle {
  left: 74px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Transition
========================== */
.switch-label, .switch-handle {
  transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}
```

I refreed this code from http://www.htmllion.com/css3-toggle-switch-button.html

Below is the output

[image]

[image]

I tried this jquery to get get:

```
 alert($(this).attr("data-on"));
```

I dont know how to get selected button data and similarly after get data it will store in database and i want to retrieve from database either yes or no it should be selected as default which will retrieve from database.How can i do with this.Result which i tried in jquery is returning undefined values.Please anyone help me to get out of this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want more - provide more code, that you've tryed

Comment: I tried in jquery similarly above code..instead of data-on i tried with span id and data-id and data-off etc..,

Comment: please, wright your task. from start to end.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.switch-input').on('change', function() {
      var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
      var selectedData;
      var $switchLabel = $('.switch-label');
      console.log('isChecked: ' + isChecked); 

      if(isChecked) {
        selectedData = $switchLabel.attr('data-on');
      } else {
        selectedData = $switchLabel.attr('data-off');
      }

      console.log('Selected data: ' + selectedData);

    });
  });

})();
```

> For Ref: http://jsbin.com/zizuxo/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Ya its working..And i want to know how can i show saved data from database in button for example if i save it as Yes in db and i wan to show button default selection as yes

Comment: Try this:

`// Params ($selector, boolean)
    function setSwitchState(el, flag) {
      el.attr('checked', flag);
    }
    
    // Usage
    setSwitchState($('.switch-input'), true);`

> Ref: http://jsbin.com/zizuxo/edit?js,console,output

@KavyaShree

Comment: I want to check the database result and set as either yes /No how can i do this

Answer (score 2):

in pure JS :

```
var result = document.getElementsByClassName("switch-input")[0].checked ? 'yes' : 'no'
```

jQuery in compatibility mode :

```
var result = jQuery('.switch-input').is(':checked')?'yes':'no';
```

Comment: please tell me, what you have in console : 
jQuery.fn.jquery

Answer (score 0):

I combined the above

```js
$('.switch-input').on('change', function() {
    result = document.getElementsByClassName("switch-input")[0].checked ? 'yes' : 'no';
    alert(result);
});
```

Comment: When you're already using jQuery there is no point of combining it with pure javascript. Also next time, take your time to format code in your answer.

Comment: @Magiczne it is needed when you want to retrieve data every time button is switched. the only javascript will give data only when a page is loaded. And thanks for editing the code for me.

Comment: You did not understand my point. Why do you use vanilla JS inside jQuery function? Accepted answer shows already better solution using only jQuery. If you posted solution using only vanilla JS it would add some value to the question. Additionaly your solution is not valid when you have more than one `.switch-input` on the page. Because it is always taking value from the first item found.